# Poor performance of memcpy for data mapped with glMapBufferRange

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, mali

I am trying to read 4 megabytes from a pixel buffer mapped with `glMapBufferRange` using memcpy. My platform is Samsung Galaxy S7 Exynos (Mali GPU). The problem is very poor performance of reading. It takes about 75 milliseconds to copy the data.

I initialize buffers like this:

```
glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, pbo_id);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, PBO_SIZE, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I read pixels to the buffers:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id[counter%NUM_BUFFERS]);
glReadPixels(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Then I read from the buffers using the following code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id[(counter - (NUM_BUFFERS-1)) % NUM_BUFFERS]);

void *ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, PBO_SIZE, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);

memcpy(&buffer, ptr, PBO_SIZE);

glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

I use previous buffers for reading to make sure that asynchronous operation finishes `pbo_id[(counter - (NUM_BUFFERS-1)) % NUM_BUFFERS]`

With just one buffer the time raises to 90 milliseconds, two and more allow to make the operation in 75 milliseconds.

I suppose that this is slow, because `memcpu` on other regions of memory finish in 1 or 2 milliseconds.

The documentation for glMapBufferRange has a note:

> Mappings to the data stores of buffer objects may have nonstandard
>   performance characteristics. For example, such mappings may be marked
>   as uncacheable regions of memory, and in such cases reading from them
>   may be very slow. To ensure optimal performance, the client should use
>   the mapping in a fashion consistent with the values of GL_BUFFER_USAGE
>   and access. Using a mapping in a fashion inconsistent with these
>   values is liable to be multiple orders of magnitude slower than using
>   normal memory.

So the question is what is wrong and how I can improve the performance of reading from buffer.

Comment: Just to check it's not stalling, does it go any faster if you use MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT?

Comment: @solidpixel, as I understand I cannot use it with MAP_READ_BIT flag for glMapBufferRange. At least the documentation says `This flag may not be used in combination with MAP_READ_BIT`

Comment: Sure, I was just trying understand where the time is going. What is the split between the `memcpy()` and the `glMapBufferRange()` call? If the `glMapBufferRange()` is stalling for a long time then it's possible you are just blocking and waiting for the GPU rendering to complete.

Comment: @solidpixel memcpy is working slow. I think I found a solution here: https://community.arm.com/graphics/f/discussions/6657/how-to-gain-performance-through-pbo-pixel-buffer-object-on-mali-t-880 I just have not tried it yet